# React-table switch sorting icon

Tags: reactjs, react-table

[Here is a link for the icon that I'm referring to. Black line at the top of the table header.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qot5g.png)

Hello I embedded a link into the question but I am trying to figure out how to switch the color of the sorting icon for React-table's library. I tried using

```
.sort-asc {
    color: green;
}
```

as well as the opposite

```
.sort-desc {
    color: green;
}
```

but all it does is change the entire table headers color and not just the icon. I tried fooling around inside inspector and I can't access the icon that way either.

Any help would much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

My fix for this is this:

```
.MyReactTableClass {
  .-sort-desc {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    &:before {
      content: "▼";
      float: right;
    }
  }

  .-sort-asc {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    &:before {
      content: "▲";
      float: right;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've been searching for how to change the default React Table `box-shadow` they use to indicate sorting for an icon. Thank you.

Comment: How to show both up, down arrow for only sortable enabled columns? so user can know those are sortable column

Answer (score 0):

```
.sort-desc {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -3px 0 0 green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that is box-shadow, you can change it easily

```css
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
```

Comment: So eventually I don't want the box shadow. I actually want to switch that sorting "icon" to a carrot to place inside the header. I actually saw that box shadow inside the css file but whenever I switch anything nothing changes.

Comment: Did you look at this: https://github.com/react-tools/react-table/issues/444#issuecomment-416374168